# Auto replace url colon parameters in angular

Tags: angularjs, parameter-passing

What is the recommended way (built in angular way) to replace the url parameters in  angular $http?
For example, How to make the following code work?

```js
$http.get(Url.parametersIt('/api/:arg1/:arg2', {arg1: 'val1', arg2: 'val2'}));
```

I want the result of 

`Url.parametersIt('/api/:arg1/:arg2', {arg1: 'val1', arg2: 'val2'})`

to be `/api/val1/val2`.

Thank you very much!

More on my thoughts. I hope there is a built in angular way to do it so I don't need to reference extra code or framework.

What I want is an client side equivalent way to do the same on server side, for example, in node koa js:

```js
var Router = require('koa-router');

Router.url('/path/:arg1/:arg2',{
  arg1: 'val1',
  arg2: 'val2'
});

// get /path/val1/val2
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `template literal` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ then he may need to use transpiler ?

Comment: @RahulNaik He can use a polyfill.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ `template literal` is good but not suitable for my project as this project uses `angular js 1.x`. And it's too complicated to add `babel ` to this project for now so `template literal` is not allowed to use to make sure the client side code can be run in most browsers.  (IE doesn't support it)

Comment: @Rahul you are right but for now this project doesn't use transpiler.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ using polyfill brings extra code. I hope there is a built in #angular way# to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For now I didn't find the **elegant angular way**, which is quite disappointed. So I had to implemented a rough one myself in my project. I hope I can delete it some other day once I found the **elegant angular way**.

```
    function url(urlTemplate, args) {
        return urlTemplate.replace(/:[^\/]+/g, function (m, capturedGroup) {
            return args[capturedGroup];
        });
    }
```

Usage:
`url('/api/:arg1/:arg2', {arg1: 'val1', arg2: 'val2'});`

get `"/api/val1/val2"`.